# ng build failing because of webpack : UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I was trying to deploy my solution using `serverless` but faced an issue, which led me to update webpack. And now I am facing altogether a new issue:

If I try to build my app i.e. `ng build --configuration=qa`, if I do it without explicit entry of webpack in devdependencies, then I get `webpack not found` error and `npm ls webpack` shows below:

[image]

If I install webpack via `npm install --save webpack` or with `-i`, I get below issue:

[image]

What just happened? Even If I restore my solution to previous conditions, when ng build was working, now it doesn't. I've tried deleting the node_modules and cache verify and all, but nothing seems to work?
What did I just mess up? Please help me understand.

Comment: it seems to be caused by multiple versions of webpack being installed at the same time. Note that angular-devkit already comes with webpack. Likely clashing with what you have. (p.s. this is for the second error)

Comment: so if I remove the independently installed webpack, I get first error. If I install, I get 2nd.

Comment: Can you add your ```package.json``` please? Hard to say without seeing what is getting pulled